# splitting field and normal extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

[image]

Regarding the forward direction of theorem $3.5.7$, can we straight away take minimal polynomial $f_1$ to be the polynomial $f$ instead of taking the product of minimal polynomials? If cannot, why?

Comment: Did you mean to ask whether $\;E\;$ can be the splitting field of one single (irreducible or not) polynomial over $\;F\;$ ? Yes, of course...most usual basic examples are this way.

Comment: If this is the case, then why the proof takes the trouble to take $f$ as union of minimal polynomial ?